# Accordions menu, strange syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I retrieved a code from [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-menu?file=src/app/accordion/accordion.component.html)

I don't understand this line:

```html
[style.height.px]="menu.active?submenu.scrollHeight: 0">
```

Is there a way to write this with another syntax?

Here is the code

```html
    <ul class="submenu" #submenu 
     [style.height.px]="menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight : 0">
       <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
         <a [href]="submenu.url">{{ submenu.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `ngStyle` attribute directive:

```html
[ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight : 0 }"
```

So the final code will look like:

```html
<ul class="submenu" #submenu [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight : 0 }">
  <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
    <a [href]="submenu.url">{{ submenu.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-menu-xpshub?file=src/app/accordion/accordion.component.html)